# Anyone else having package-problems with their old Code on a new laptop?

Tags: errors, packages, preamble

I am facing the following Problem. I am using a preambel in LaTex that I need for a specific Type of document for my university. However I am not able to use the exact same code on a different Laptop. I use MiKTeX together with TeXstudio. I uninstalled and installed both of them multiple times and tried to use the Code in TeXlive to no avail. I even set up a virtual machine with Ubuntu to determine if the error is a windows-problem. No its not. I get the exact same error message. I have multiple friend who use the same code as preambel and have no problems, just as me on my old laptop. The error is:

"Command \ifpdftex already defined. }"

I think there most have been a change in the packages I am using, so only old versions work ( which all of us are using, since we installed it 6 months ago ). The error seems to appear in pdfcprot.sty in line 703, which I cant remove since its appearently eesential. I am very new to the subject and really dont understand my mistake. Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,                                        
    12pt,                                           
    twoside,                                        
    headsepline,                                
    footsepline,                                    
    captions=tableheading,                  
    numbers=endperiod,
]{scrartcl}
\brokenpenalty=10000

%\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}  
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot, output-product = \cdot, separate-uncertainty=true}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{graphicx}                   
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}                     
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol\nobond{-[3,0.2,,,draw=none]}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}                  
\usepackage{amsmath}                        
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{FP}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{verbatim}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.4pt} %Dicke der Linien am Anfang und Ende jeder Tabelle
\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.4pt} %Dicke der Linien nach header
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{amssymb}                    
\usepackage{longtable}                  
\usepackage{geometry}                   
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{ae}                             
\usepackage[activate]{pdfcprot}     
\usepackage{setspace}                   
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}                   
\usepackage{mhchem}                     
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}                                        
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf,it},tablename=Tab.,figurename=Abb.}             
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,justification=justified}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=justified}              

%\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}           Acronymverzeichnis                  
\usepackage{svg}

\renewcommand*\figureformat {\figurename~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\thefigure.}  
\renewcommand*\tableformat {\tablename~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\thetable:}     
\renewcommand*\captionformat {~}                                




\pgfplotstableset{
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule[0.4pt]},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}}

\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand*\cite[1]{\textsuperscript{\oldcite{#1}}}


\sisetup{group-digits=true,
    group-four-digits=true,
    group-separator = {\,},
    output-decimal-marker = {.}}

\pgfplotsset{
    siunitxlabels/.style={
        /pgfplots/typeset ticklabel/.code={\pgfmathparse{\tick}$\num[zero-decimal-to-integer]{\pgfmathresult}$},
    },
}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bib@heading{\subsubsection{\bibname}         
\@mkboth{\subsubsectionmarkformat \bibname}{\subsubsectionmarkformat \bibname}}
\makeatother
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand*\bibname{Literatur}} 

\usepackage{prettyref}                       x.x.# anpassen
%%% Für Abbildungen %%%
\newrefformat{fig}{Abb.~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\ref{#1}}
%%% Für Tabellen %%%
\newrefformat{tab}{Tab.~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\ref{#1}}
%%% Für Formeln
\newrefformat{eq}{Gl.~\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\ref{#1}}
%%% Für chem. Formeln
\newrefformat{ceq}{Gl.~\ref{#1}}




\usepackage[                                    
    linkcolor=black,                            
    citecolor=black,                            
    urlcolor=black,                             
    colorlinks=true,                            
]{hyperref}                                     
%\renewcommand\citeform[1]{[#1]}


\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.}{1.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}{1.2em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.}{0.75em}{}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}     %Serifenschrift in Überschriften
\setkomafont{section}{\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
\pagenumbering{arabic}                  
\geometry{left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm}   
\parindent 0pt
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                                     
\parskip 12pt                                   
\onehalfspacing                             
\pagestyle{scrheadings}                 
\headsep0.4cm                               
\footskip0.8cm                                  
\urlstyle{same}                             

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
%runin=false,
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
%runin=false,
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=.75\baselineskip,
afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
%runin=false,
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
```

I woul really appreciate any help. Thanks !

Best Regards

Comment: Remove pdfcprot.. Remove also ae.  These packages are outdated.

Comment: Tried commenting out and it actually worked. On my old laptop it does with the packages on my new one it doesnt. Strange. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @allthegoodnamesweretakenBert Do you upgrade your packages on your old laptop from time to time? If your old laptop runs an old MiKTeX installation, it's not surprising that some outdated packages can work without problems there, but not on a new MiKTeX installation.

Comment: Finish your project and update ***later***!

Comment: @Vincent I guess you must be right. No I dont since i was happy with the way everything was working out. I might do it just out of crouriosity to check if the same error will appear. Are there updates for this packages, wich will allow me to use them again on newer MiKTeX ?

Comment: @allthegoodnamesweretakenBert Updating MiKTeX now on your old computer will most probably cause the error to show up. It's a good idea to always keep an up-to-date MiKTeX installation, because if you don't you will probably run into compatibility problems once in a while when downloading new packages, which expect the up-to-date installation.